# How GROUP BY and COUNT or SUM works together in SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I wonder how `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` or `SUM` works together in SQL queries.

For example, why does the following code successfully use the `SUM` function on the rows within each group, not the groups itself?

```
SELECT 
    product_name,
    SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(company_name, '|', -1) LIKE '%live%' AS count_live,
    SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(company_name, '|', -1) LIKE '%demo%' AS count_demo,
 SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(company_name, '|', -1) NOT LIKE '%live%' AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(company_name, '|', -1) NOT LIKE '%demo%') AS count_other,
 COUNT(*) AS total
FROM foo GROUP BY product_name ORDER BY total DESC
;
```

How it is executed? Which part of this expression executed earlier?

Comment: what do you mean for "not the groups itself"?

Comment: @scaisEdge I mean why does it count the rows within each group, not the whole table's content or something like this?

Comment: I have posted an asnwer ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate function like `sum` or `count` return result based on a group of rows (aggregated by the column specified in group by clause) then in you case you obtain both: the sum of the value contained in the rows with the  same product_name and the count of these rows.

The group by condition lead the aggregation and work for all the Aggregate funtion in same way ..

Comment: So it's just a rule and such functions like `SUM` and `COUNT` will return group-based result when `GROUP BY` specified and return values for all rows when it is omitted, right?

Comment: @FrozenHeart if you try to have an aggregate function without a group by specified, it should yell at you that there is no group by